# Edições de formatação em perguntas fechadas devem ser feitas/aprovadas?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, edições-sugeridas

É sabido que algumas perguntas podem ser fechadas não simplesmente por estarem **mal formatadas**. Como foi o caso da pergunta a que me refiro: [Node.js ou Php?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/369050/node-js-ou-php)

Acontece que foi feita e aprovada uma edição limitada à formatação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Votei contra a [edição da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/214874) seguindo a premissa de que **não resulta em uma melhoria significativa para a pergunta ser reaberta**.

Justamente por ter sido aprovada tal edição, trago essa questão a debate com o objetivo de aplicar nos próximos casos semelhantes que "cair na minha mão" na fila de análise.

Reitero: essa **edição está limitada à formatação**. Isso significa que ela **continua sendo baseada em opiniões** (inclusive votei favorável ao fechamento desta) e não se estende à edições que realmente melhoram a pergunta a ponto dela poder ser votada para reabertura.

Contudo, se ignorar o contexto da pergunta, realmente a edição foi boa. Sem dúvida, eu aprovaria. Mas nesse caso em específico, foi uma edição em vão. Visivelmente não é suficiente para ela ser reaberta.

E, lógico que após essa edição ter sido aprovada, a pergunta caiu na fila de análise de reabertura.

Comment: A edição não foi boa, ainda mais neste caso no qual a pergunta não faz parte do escopo (poderia editar mais coisas, o titulo e remover algumas coisas). De qqr forma, eu rejeitaria também. Mas, fique atento, há edições de apenas formatações que melhoram a pergunta. E tudo que você precisa fazer é comparar a edição com a anterior e vê se esta mais compreensível.

Comment: Eu rejeitaria tb porque a edição torna até a pergunta esteticamente melhor e mais organizada, mas não altera o entendimento, que, ao meu ver, é o principal.

Comment: A pergunta ficará mais legível e compreensível para leitura, independente se esteja irregular ou regular. A edição não tem propósito de fazer uma pergunta/resposta entrar no padrão, apenas aperfeiçoa-la, seja para compreensão, formatação e/ou leitura.

Answer (score 5):

O fato de estarem fechadas não quer dizer que uma edição deve ser aprovada ou rejeitada. O que vale é a premissa de que a **edição tornou a pergunta mais fácil de ser compreendida**.

Isso quer dizer que o fator estético não tem grande influência na compreensão do texto. Pelo exemplo dado, a edição feita teve apenas a intenção de organizar esteticamente a pergunta, porém o texto continuou o mesmo, e isso não prejudica e nem melhora a sua compreensão.

Ao meu ver, uma pergunta fechada deveria ser editada apenas com o intuito de melhorar a sua qualidade contrapondo o motivo que a fez ser fechada, e não para deixá-la mais "bonitinha". Logo, qualquer edição no sentido de melhorar a qualidade da pergunta para que ela possa ser reaberta ou ser uma boa referência deve ser aprovada, mas para finalidades estéticas apenas, ao meu ver deve ser rejeitada, pois não altera o seu teor.

Comment: Não concordo com esse negócio de 'rejeitar quando for somente finalidade estética', se for seguir isso a risca, edições que somente inserem formatação de código-fonte não são uma edição por estética? :) Tem que olhar todo o contexto, na minha opinião a edição foi ok, colocou como lista as perguntas existentes no texto (ficou até melhor de ler, batendo o olho dá pra notar claramente uma melhora no diff das duas), o problema é a pergunta que é baseada em opiniões óras.

Comment: Formatação de código eu acho válido, mas tb apenas quando isso for facilitar a compreensão da pergunta. Em mts casos a pergunta em si já é ruim (por isso foi fechada) e formatar o código não vai ajudar em nada.

Comment: @Renan Então. O meu questionamento é se devemos fazer/aprovar edições **exclusivas à formatação** em perguntas que estão, claramente, fora do escopo do site. Nesse caso, como exemplo, a pergunta é baseada em opiniões. A responsabilidade de editar é do autor. E ele deve não só tornar a pergunta mais fácil de ser lida/compreendida, mas também ajustar ao escopo do site.

Comment: Pra mim a questão é bem simples: a edição torna a pergunta mais fácil de ser compreendida? Se vc acha que sim, aprova, se não, rejeita, seja qual for o tipo de edição. Na minha visão, colocar negrito, itálico etc.. não melhora o sentido do texto.